# Entity tracking in multiple contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

in a typical MVC3 app with an EF model, each controller instantiates its own copy of the model container.  this means that if I were to create a class in a different file and it needed access to the model, it would need to instantiate its own container.

Consider the following:

```
namespace X.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        EFContainer db = new EFContainer();

        public ActionResult Whatever()
        {
            User u = db.Users.Find(3);
            ...
        }
```

if I wanted to abstract my fetching of a user in a class `Auth` then it would have to instantiate its own `db` since it doesn't have access to the controller's -- all fine until the controller wants to make changes to the returned object:

```
    public ActionResult Whatever()
    {
        User u = Auth.GetUser();
        u.Name = "ekkis";
        db.SaveChanges();
        ...
    }
```

since the user at that point belongs to a different context... so either I have to share my `db` with `Auth` or perhaps I'd have to do a moronic double-lookup:

```
    public ActionResult Whatever()
    {
        int id = Auth.GetUserId();
        User u = db.Users.Find(id);
        u.Name = "ekkis";
        db.SaveChanges();
        ...
    }
```

what is the recommended way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass in your model / EF context via constructor injection into your `Auth` class? That seems to be the most reasonable way (same applies to your controller actually once you have an IOC container set up).

```
public class Auth
{
    public Auth(EFContainer db) 
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Ideally you would also make this work based on an abstract interface so you can test `Auth` independently of EF.

Comment: yeah.  I guess.  I wondered how people usually do this.  thanks.